# how do I make an enemy target an ally unit?

Tags: xna, c#, path-finding

I have 2 different classes, a EnemyFighter class, and a EnemyBomber class. both are planes that I have that can fly around the map.( i also have AllyFighter, and AllyBomber)

So far they can follow me, and eachother, but how would I set up a target variable or something?

like I could set up a target variable for the enemyfighter

```
AllyFighter target;
```

and a variable holding the location of the allyfighter as a Vector2.

but then what if I want to target an AllyBomber? do I have to make 2 variables? or is there some other approach I should take?

Thanks

EDIT:
Maybe a better question would be how can I target different enemy types (ones with different classes)? or at least hold there information in a 'target' variable

Comment: If you absolutely need to split those units up into separate classes you should look into polymorphism: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you'd have some parent class that all these classes inherit from. For example, if all of your planes inherited from `Plane`, then you could easily create a list of those different classes with something like:

```
List<Plane> targets = new List<Plane>();
```

Now you can add all your targets to the same list. Of course you can just have a single target too:

```
Plane target;
```

And then as long as `AllyFighter`, `AllyBomber` and so on all extend `Plane`, you can use the same variable.

Do note that you will only be able to access the data that's commonly stored your targets at the `Plane` level (apart from casting the object to the correct type). This means you'll want to store the important information for targeting at the `Plane` level (you likely would anyway since most of the information is going to be common to them all). So stuff like position, health, armor, etc. should be data inside `Plane` not inside `AllyBomber`.